# French language videos for an absolute beginner (free)?

Tags: ressources

I am trying to learn French. Can anyone suggest videos where you can learn French for free? A brief search throws up videos from Americans who have studied French for only a couple years. I am trying to learn from someone who has a genuine French accent. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want a video lecture, or a movie ?

Comment: I am in the same situation, I've been watching french preschool programs on You Tube and reading preschool books too.

Comment: I think @oli mentions a good hint. I, personally, consider movies more helpful than video lectures since situations, conversations and such are more natural than in lectures or tutorials.

Answer (score 5):

If you are really serious (meaning you can stick with it), I suggest [French In Action (FIA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_in_Action), which can be found on YouTube and other places, including [here at learner.org](http://www.learner.org/resources/series83.html). It consists of a total of 52 half-hour episodes, for 26 hours of language immersion. It is well worth going through them all.

If you know absolutely no French, you should look into Rosetta Stone to get acquainted with the language. Unfortunately, it is not free. Even with Rosetta Stone, I recommend FIA.

Comment: I used [Pimsleur](http://www.pimsleurapproach.com/learn-french/) as complementary listen-only course when I started studying French. It was nice for walking around listening to the lessons. It is really basic though, a "bonjour, comment allez-vous" kind of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try some of the Youtube channels I use:

https://www.youtube.com/@lequipe/videos: It's a sports channel, and you don't really need to understand the commentators to watch the videos.

https://www.youtube.com/@SportenFrance/videos See above

https://www.youtube.com/@maprofdefrancais/videos: She uses simple vocabulary and a bunch of her videos are subtitled.

https://www.youtube.com/@HistoireGeoYT/videos: Most videos are subtitled and the maps help you follow along. Plus, English versions of all the videos exist here: https://www.youtube.com/@GeoHistory/videos

https://www.youtube.com/@InfoouMytho/videos: Videos are short and simple

https://www.youtube.com/@TotallySpiesFrancais/videos

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/21786)